# Creating combinations from multiple columns in data set in SAS

Tags: sas, combinations

This relates to one of my previous questions ([SAS - Creating combinations of different independant variables with lags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232898/sas-creating-combinations-of-different-independant-variables-with-lags)). The HAVE matrix looks like below. Is there an easy way in SAS to create combinations from variables appearing in the multiple columns?
E.g. columns headings Var1, Var2, Var3 - 
Var1               Var2      Var3

VarA               VarB      VarC

VarA1              VarB1     VarC1

..

VarA4              VarB4     VarC4

The combinations would be either - 
a) selecting any two columns e.g. Var1 and Var2 and then selecting one element from each column e.g. one combination could be VarA1 VarB2
b) selecting all columns and one element from each.
I want to have all such possible combinations in a) and b). I searched through for this including proc plan but couldn't get much. Is there is proc to do all such combinations for multiple columns?

PS: VarA, VarA1, ..VarB, VarB1,..all of them are just text/strings.

Thanks

To add, I saw through http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n082a03omu3i21n1k889zfklh4ps.htm which could work for 2 columns, but would get cumbersome with multiple columns..

! [EDIT]
WANT matrix could be something like below (considering only two lags ..)

VarA    VarB
VarA    VarB1
VarA    VarB2
VarA1   VarB
VarA1   VarB1
VarA1   VarB2
…   …
VarB    VarC
VarB    VarC1
VarB    VarC2
VarB1   VarC
VarB1   VarC1
VarB1   VarC2
…   …
VarA    VarC
VarA    VarC1
VarA    VarC2
…   …

VarA    VarB    VarC
VarA    VarB    VarC1
VarA    VarB    VarC2
VarA    VarB1   VarC
VarA    VarB1   VarC1
VarA    VarB1   VarC2
VarA    VarB2   VarC
VarA    VarB2   VarC1
VarA    VarB2   VarC2
…   …   …

Comment: Your question is not clear and I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Is this by any chance creating interaction variables for regression analysis? Anyway, you may want to provide a more concrete example output of what you want.

Comment: Right, I want to design all combinations of input variables with different lags. Edited post to show output.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the best way to do this is to transpose your original dataset to one column, then join it to itself using a cartesian join (or any of the other methods mentioned in the paper you posted).  As long as you want the combination of *everything* with *everything else* or some subset, the vertical transpose is very easy.  Then just remove the combinations you don't want using WHERE; so for example if you want only cross-column combinations, your data looks like you could use SUBSTR to look at the 4th character ('A' 'B' 'C') and just remove any where they are equal.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, i was able to get it to work for creating combinations of two column elements. But I'm thinking of ways I could build this further to have it flexible to take care of multiple columns selecting picking multiple elements. Say creating all 2,3,4 element combinations from 4 columns. Like in the example in the question it would be all combinations with two variables and with all three variables at different lags.

Comment: In an alternate arrangement, using proc plan i was able to create a data set listing all combinations as numbers. Is there an easy way to fill this entire data set by extracting corresponding row observations from the single column data set (which was formed using vertical transpose you indicated above)? E.g. if the combination set is [1 10] pick the first and tenth element from single column data set.